# Boolean Operation on Extruded Edge

Tags: modifiers

I need to clean up a mesh and thought of using boolean operation to remove the unwanted part. But the 'hanging' edges don't seem to be affected by the boolean operation. For example: if I have a cube and I extrude an edge, I thought a booeal difference with another object overlapping this edge would slice it off. Which doesn't seem to be the case. I get similar results with other boolean operations and even boolean modifier behaves the same way.

Is there a way I can achieve the objective of cutting off a portion of an object via another suitably shaped object?

[image: boolean difference on edge]

Comment: Boolean operations only work well-ish on manifold gemoetry

Comment: I get the best (but still unsatisfying) results by adding thickness to planes with the Solidify modifier